# python regex) pattern '\d-\d' with string '1-4-1'

Tags: python, regex

I have a quick question as my code below:

```
import re

s = '1-4-1'
p = '\d-\d'
re.findall(p,s)

>> ['1-4']
>> but what I expected is: ['1-4', '4-1']
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQY3Zd/1)

I have no idea why the pattern cannot catch '4-1'

Comment: `\d-\d` already matched and consumed `4`, the engine only starts to search for the next match after the previous match.

Comment: Try `(?=(\d-\d))` it should grab the group match.

Comment: Try the following `>>>import regex as re>>>s = '1-4-1'>>>matches = re.findall(r'\d-\d', s, overlapped=True)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I haven't heard the word 'consume' in regex before. I will search it. Thanks.

Comment: It means the text was matched and appended to a match value, and the regex index got moved after this text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, so the pattern won't be re-used.